# Should Web API return 403 Forbidden or not have an endpoint at all?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, url-routing, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a web API and for one Model, I only allow to get by id `[GET] api/models/{modelId}` or update `[PUT] api/models/{modelId}`. API doesn't support `POST`, `DELETE` or get collection (`[GET] api/models`).

Should still have these methods in the `Controller` and return `Forbid()` 403 status?

Or should I simply remove these methods?

Comment: If they aren't supported, don't include them at all

Comment: How about `501 Not Implemented`

Comment: or If the server does recognize the method, but intentionally does not support it, the appropriate response is `405 Method Not Allowed`

Comment: With .Net Core, if you try to `POST` to any known route with an HTTP verb that is not allowed, you will get the `405 Method Not Allowed` response anyhow. So in this case if you `POST api/models/{modelId}` you'll get a `405`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full list of [HTTP response status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) may help you identify the most appropriate response.

`403 Forbidden` does not fit the situation you describe:

> The client does not have access rights to the content; that is, it is unauthorized, so the server is refusing to give the requested resource. Unlike 401, the client's identity is known to the server.

On the other hand, **`405 Method Not Allowed`** seems to fit this scenario:

> The request method is known by the server but has been disabled and cannot be used. For example, an API may forbid DELETE-ing a resource. The two mandatory methods, `GET` and `HEAD`, must never be disabled and should not return this error code.

[Note](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405):

> The server MUST generate an Allow header field in a 405 response containing a list of the target resource's currently supported methods.

Comment: Thanks! I just want to reference @Matt U comment under my question: *"With .Net Core, if you try to POST to any known route with an HTTP verb that is not allowed, you will get the 405 Method Not Allowed response anyhow"* Which means, I simply remove these methods from the `Controller`